# Do you keep the true distribution between classes when you manually create your own dataset, or do you make it balanced?

Tags: dataset, data-science

(I struggled a bit to phrase the title - please feel free to suggest another title).

I have a text-dataset which I need to classify, say there's three classes. I need to create the targets by manually setting the labels based on the text (say the three classes are `dog`,`cat`,`bird`).

When I do so I notice we have, say, 70% dog, 20% cat and 10% bird.

Since a lot of machine learning models struggle with imbalanced data, my first thought would be to force the dataset being balanced simply to ignore some of the `dog` and `cat` text (i.e "undersampling") thus ending up with (almost) a balanced dataset, making it more easy to train the model.

My concern is though that if we want to train e.g a neural network and get the probability for each class, not training over the correct distribution of the data would result in over/under-confident predictions?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed if your **dataset is imbalanced**, there is a **risk of affecting the performance of your classifier**.

You'll find plenty of libraries to help you deal with this problem (see below) and the bottom line is if **classes are equally represented in your dataset, it can only help prevent biais of your classifier**:
https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/index.html#general-examples
https://github.com/ufoym/imbalanced-dataset-sampler
https://github.com/MaxHalford/pytorch-resample etc...
*(but you can also do that sampling yourself, shouldn't be too difficult, eg [libraries like pandas have such functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html))*

**As a safeguard, split your dataset into 3**:

- **Training** (eg 70% of our data): the bulk of the data used for learning
- **Validation** (eg 20%): what your classifier uses for regularization (ie to prevent over fitting)
- **Test** (eg 10%): `this data is NEVER exposed to your classifier` for learning purposes, you keep it separate and just use it at the end on your model to evaluate its **true performance** (you call predict and compare with expected classes).

This should be a good starting point.